# Time elapsed between two 8-bit timestamps

Tags: normalization, time-stamp

So I have a sets of numbers representing some timings.
This is how they look like:

```
[sec]   [msec]

 100    75
 100    200
 101    60
 101    233
 102    255
 104    21
```

First column contains the elapsed seconds, and the second one the elapsed milliseconds. Values are represented using **8bit** (so if the *ms* number is bigger than *255*, the *sec* one gets incremented).

Now what I want to do, is to calculate the elapsed time (in milliseconds) between two inteframing values.

What I managed to do is this:

```
First interframe:   200 - 75                = 125ms.
Second interframe:  (1 * 255 + 60) - 200    = 115ms.
Third interframe:   233 - 60                = 173ms.
Forth interframe:   (1 * 255 + 255) - 233   = 277ms.
Fifth interframe:   (2 * 255 + 21) - 255    = 276ms.
```

But this method is kinda hard to implement...

Is there any other method to find the elapsed time (in milliseconds) using another method?

Comment: How is it milliseconds if it's incremented at 255? It's actually 1/256ths of a second, isn't it?

Comment: ...I'd probably start by getting a 16bit timestamp representing milliseconds.

Comment: Maybe he is within some hardware with this limitation

Comment: @André Well there are only so many values per bit. Either he'll need to use lower resolution (e.g. 10ms) increments or a single 16-bit value for seconds and miliseconds (basically just milliseconds) which can count up to ~6.5 seconds.

Comment: @Rotem I'm not actually sure what they represent... but the presented method works, if the `sec` bytes are identical, substract the `msec` ones, and you'll get the elapsed msec. This is all the info. that I got.
L.E. It may actually be 1/256ths of a second.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I can't, I'm stuck with this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about 1/256ths of a second  (let's humorously call them bittiseconds), and not milliseconds, you could simply convert two values to their bittisecond representation, and then do a straight subtraction.

```
int ToBittiseconds(byte seconds, byte bittiseconds)
{
    return seconds * 256 + bittiseconds;
}

byte v1Seconds = 100;
byte v1Bittis = 200;

byte v2Seconds = 101;
byte v2Bittis = 60;

int difference = ToBittiseconds(v2Seconds, v2Bittis) - ToBittiseconds(v1Seconds, v1Bittis);
```